# Removing rows which have variables with partial NAs

Tags: r, na

I have a variable that contains partial NAs. It is a variable representing a time period ranging from startyear to endyear, however where endyear and ongoingasofyear are missing the period ranges to NA.

```
#     startyear endyear ongoingasofyear imposition sanctions_period
#1      1945    1947              NA          1        1945-1947
#2      1946    1949              NA          1        1946-1949
#3      1946    1993              NA          1        1946-1993
#4      1946    NA                NA          1        1946-NA
#5      1946    1946              NA          1        1946-1946
#6      1946      NA              NA          1        1946-NA
```

How can i remove the observations that contain a NA in the sanctions_period? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe with `df[!grepl("NA", df$sanctions_period, fixed = TRUE), ]` where `df` is your data.

Comment: Is there a reason to not just use `df[! (is.na(endyear) & is.na(ongoingasofyear)),]`?

Comment: Another one would be to check both columns at once `df[!rowSums(is.na(df[2:3])) == 2, ]`

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in command for this:  complete.cases()

```
d1 <- read.table(header=TRUE,text="
startyear endyear ongoingasofyear imposition sanctions_period
1945    1947              NA          1        1945-1947
1946    1949              NA          1        1946-1949
1946    1993              NA          1        1946-1993
1946    NA                NA          1        1946-NA
1946    1946              NA          1        1946-1946
1946      NA              NA          1        1946-NA")

d2 <- d1[complete.cases(d1[c("startyear","endyear")]),]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use sqldf

library(sqldf)

df<- read.csv("df.csv", header= TRUE, sep = "")

sqldf(c("delete from df where sanctions_period like '%-NA%'", "select * from df"))